# Why is the image not saved if I place the site online (host) but if it is local everything goes well?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a website and I'm trying to allow the user to save an image locally (I don't want it on the server). I have javascript code which works locally for me and I can save the image without any problems. It is displayed on the screen and does not disappear, but if I place it online it does not work.

Online I am getting the console error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
at FileReader.reader.onload (VM71:27)
```

HTML code:

```
 <img style="width: 20%;" src="#" id="photo_view" />
 <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" accept="image/*" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
```

Javascript code:

```
   $("#photo_view").attr("src", localStorage.getItem('savedImage') || '#') // restore

function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    const reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function (e) { 
    $(".file-upload-image").attr("src", e.target.result);  
    $(".image-title").html(input.files[0].name);

    if (localStorage.getItem('savedImage')) {
      localStorage.removeItem('savedImage');
    }
    localStorage.setItem('savedImage', e.target.result);
  }; 
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  } 
}
```

Where is the mistake and how can I correct it?

Link to the online site: https://bravojob.000webhostapp.com/

There are several other errors in the console, but they appear due to the advertising of the free hosting site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your site uses HTTPS but attempts to load jQuery from an insecure location (HTTP). Many modern browsers will block that by default. If that's the case, you should be seeing error messages in the browser console.

Comment: You can go in the `Network` tab and select `JS` you will see that  __Jquery__ is indeed not laoded.

Comment: Yes, I realized that jquery is not loading, but what can I do to fix the error? host my site on http and everything will work? - Sergiu Condratiuc just now Edit

Comment: How about loading jQuery through HTTPS?

Comment: give it to me to receive it, if jquery is with https everything works, but it works if the jqery page copies it in a new .js document or on html I can load it still works: D: D, thank you very much

Comment: If the URL that the user is opening (the one that's on the browser bar) starts with `https://` then the browser expects (and requires) that everything else is encrypted too. If the URL starts with `http://` the browser will typically show an **insecure site** icon but will load the site anyway—otherwise it'd break lots of sites.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is attempting to run jQuery before the library is loaded, which takes some time to request when your site is being loaded from a remote server. You can wait for jQuery to load by wrapping it in a test for for document ready.

```
$(function() {
    ...
});
```

See: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: The HTTP vs. HTTPS answer is correct, but you should still implement the document ready code above.